# VBA return value from option button

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

Okay I'm new to VBA and the solution is probably very simple.

I have an Option Button (named Matrix) and if the button **is checked** I want the global variable rdb to get the value from the Cell (5,2). 
This is my attempt:

```
    Public rdb as Integer
    Public Sub Matrix_Change()
    If Matrix.Value = True Then rdb = Cells(5, 2).Value
    End Sub
```

I noticed that this only works if I switch between two radiobuttons. This is perhaps because I selected "Change". How can I create a sub that only checks if the option button is checked? Simply removing the "_Change" part will lead to an error. Also is it possible to return the value from the Sub instead of using global variables?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: would you explain in more detail the exact behavior you'd expect to reach from the code?

Comment: never mind, I've solved the problem. thanks!

Comment: Thank for the feedback. BTW using `MouseUp()` event seems quite weird to me. If you are interested, you may want to give a little more detail and I can help you with an alternative solution

Comment: I have multiple radio buttons and just wanted to assign a value from a certain cell depending on which button is checked. I realised that I can simply create a new Sub in which I go through all radio buttons and call this sub in another sub. Like this : `Public Sub rdbChecker()  If rdb1.Value = True Then rdb = Cells(5, 2).Value If rdb2.Value = True Then rdb = Cells(5, 4).Value` etc and then just type `rdbChecker ` in another Sub to call it. I'm new to VBA and still playing a little bit with it :-) Thanks for your support!

Comment: I guess you're right with that code, provided you properly set `rdb1`. `rdb2`, ... to your specific worksheet checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(First Question)** Choose the **MouseUp** Event instead of the **Change** Event

**(Second Question)** A Sub is unable to return a value

You can simply Replace Your Code to this:

```
Public rdb As Integer

Public Sub Matrix__MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Matrix.Value = True Then rdb = Cells(5, 2).Value
End Sub
```